# Horizontal orientated WrapPanel within ItemsControl lists vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, itemscontrol

I have two DataTemplates defined within my XAML, each used for a seperate ItemsControl panel.

The main ItemsControl lists Foo objects stored within an ObservableCollection object.

The Foo object itself has its own set of items stored within as an ObservableCollection object.

I tried to define the XAML in a way that allows for each of the ObservableCollection Foo items to be displayed with its name in a header (The first ItemsControl). From this the list within each Foo item itself should be displayed horizontally (Using the second ItemsControl) with a related field directly below. If enough items are present then they should wrap to the next line where necessary.

This is how the UI currently stands:

[image: Incorrect UI]

This is how I wish the UI to actually appear:

[image: Correct UI]

My Markup (Button controls are for another aspect of the UI) :

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="ContentList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GameTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Background="DarkGray">
            <Button Click="OnLoad">_Load</Button>
            <Button Click="OnSave">_Save</Button>
            <Button Click="OnAdd">_Add</Button>
            <Button Click="OnDelete">_Delete</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

DataTemplate for listing Foo items:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GameTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" Background="Gray" FontSize="16" />
                <ItemsControl x:Name="imageContent" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding FileList}" 
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GameImagesTemplate}" 
                              Grid.Row="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

DataTemplate for listing items within each Foo item:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GameImagesTemplate">
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <Image Source="{Binding FileInfo.FullName}" 
                       Margin="8,8,8,8" 
                       Height="70" 
                       Width="70" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I'm fairly new to WPF so I have a feeling it's an issue caused by how I am using the controls.

What WPF changes would I need to make in order to generate the UI I would like?

Comment: There is nothing that jumps out as wrong with your XAML. Can you post how you are populating the data?

Comment: An example implementation of both vertical and horizontal based scrolling for ItemsControl item displays:   http://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/how-to-orient-wrappanel-items-within-itemscontrol-lists-vertically-and-horizontally/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think its because you are adding each image item to a new `WrapPanel` in `GameImagesTemplate` , you should just have to set the `ItemsControl` `ItemsPanelTemplate` to `WrapPanel` in the `GameTemplate`

**Example:**

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="252.351" Width="403.213" Name="UI" >
    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="GameImagesTemplate" >
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding FileInfo.FullName}" Margin="8,8,8,8" Height="70" Width="70" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="GameTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" Background="Gray" FontSize="16" />
                <ItemsControl x:Name="imageContent" ItemsSource="{Binding FileList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GameImagesTemplate}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=FileList}" Grid.Column="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GameTemplate}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Foo> _fileList = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (var item in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\StackOverflow"))
        {
            FileList.Add(new Foo
            {
                Name = item,
                FileList = new ObservableCollection<Bar>(Directory.GetFiles(item).Select(x => new Bar { FileInfo = new FileInfo(x) }))
            });
        }
    } 

    public ObservableCollection<Foo> FileList
    {
        get { return _fileList; }
        set { _fileList = value; }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Bar> FileList { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see exactly where I was going wrong. Thank you for detailed answer - +1 and an accept for you!