# Select item in a Wrap Panel & item style wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have followed the solution in this thread: [Horizontal orientated WrapPanel within ItemsControl lists vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803803/horizontal-orientated-wrappanel-within-itemscontrol-lists-vertically)

And I have two questions:
1) The items are not selectable? How can I achieve this?
2) How can I add a style resource to every item in the wrap panel so it is contained in a border?

Answer (score 0):

the linked answer uses ItemsControl with WrapPanel. ItemsControl doesn't support selection out of box, you should use ListBox, for example.

to display every item in a Border modify DataTemplates:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1">
    <!--other visuals here-->
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks ASh. I´ll try this tonight.